# Usage of {{block type="bla/blubb"}} in WYSIWYG backend forms

Tags: magento-1.9, attributes, wysiwyg, editor

I want to implement a `{{block type="bla/blubb"}}` in a newly generated Magento Category Attribute, which is configured as a WYSIWYG field.

However, if I put my code into that attribute in the backend, it doesn't get rendered, instead I get the output `{{block type="bla/blubb"}}`.

The same code is working fine when I place it into a CMS Page in Magento, `{{block type="bla/blubb"}}` will get rendered there fine.

I installed the attribute this way:

```
$entityTypeId = $installer->getEntityTypeId('catalog_category');
$attributeSetId = $installer->getDefaultAttributeSetId($entityTypeId);
$attributeGroupId = $installer->getDefaultAttributeGroupId($entityTypeId, $attributeSetId);
$fieldName = 'my_attribute_name';

if (!$installer->getAttributeId($entityTypeId, $fieldName)) {
    $installer->addAttribute("catalog_category", $fieldName, array(
        "type" => "text",
        "backend" => "",
        "frontend" => "",
        "label" => "Attribute Label",
        "input" => "textarea",
        "class" => "",
        "source" => "",
        "global" => Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Eav_Attribute::SCOPE_STORE,
        "visible" => true,
        "required" => false,
        "user_defined" => false,
        "default" => "",
        "searchable" => false,
        "filterable" => false,
        "comparable" => false,
        "wysiwyg_enabled" => 1,
        "is_html_allowed_on_front" => true,
        "visible_on_front" => true,
        "unique" => false,
        "note" => "Description"
    ));

    $installer->addAttributeToGroup(
        $entityTypeId,
        $attributeSetId,
        $attributeGroupId,
        $fieldName,
        '10'
    );
}
```

What would I need to do in order to get `{{ }}` tags working? I've added the block already to be whitelisted in Blocks output and activated the dynamic media output, which does something else (as Marius suggested).

I'm using Magento 1.9.3.4

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this solves it, but you can try to set the config setting `System->Configuration->Catalog->Frontend->Allow Dynamic Media URLs in Products and Categories` to `yes`.
This will allow for sure directives like `{{media ... }}`. maybe it works for blocks also.

Comment: Already activated, not working. :(

Answer (score 0):

Add `bla/blubb` in the allowed blocks in **Admin > System > Permissions > Blocks**

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/139836)

Comment: @Jai updated :)

Comment: This is already enabled and is verified to be working when injecting the Code in my question in CMS blocks. They are intended to work there and do work properly.